# Can Object.GetType() ever return null?

Tags: c#, types

Merely curious.

Is there any time when calling `.GetType()` on an object will return null?

Hypothetical usage:

```
public Type MyMethod( object myObject )
{
    return myObject.GetType();
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

GetType on an object can never return null - at the very least it will be of type object. if myObject is null, then you'll get an exception when  you try to call GetType() anyway

Comment: This answer is no longer true after introducing `dynamic` keyword and meta-programming in C#! See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42968060/375958

Answer (score 5):

No, it will not return `null`. But here is a gotcha to be aware of!

```
static void WhatAmI<T>() where T : new() { 
    T t = new T(); 
    Console.WriteLine("t.ToString(): {0}", t.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("t.GetHashCode(): {0}", t.GetHashCode());
    Console.WriteLine("t.Equals(t): {0}", t.Equals(t)); 

    Console.WriteLine("t.GetType(): {0}", t.GetType()); 
}
```

Here's the output for a certain `T`:

```
t.ToString():
t.GetHashCode(): 0
t.Equals(t): True

Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to
an instance of an object.
```

What is `T`? Answer: any `Nullable<U>`.

(Credit orginal concept to Marc Gravell.)

Comment: @Marc Gravell: I did credit you if that is what you mean. I couldn't find the post where you first presented that though to provide a link? I thought it was in the C#/.NET gotcha thread.

Answer (score 2):

If the myObject parameter is null, then you won't be able to call GetType() on it.  A NullReferenceException will be thrown.  Otherwise, I think you will fine.

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype(VS.85).aspx

MSDN only lists a type object as the return value.

I'd imagine other than that all you can get is a "not set to an instance of an object" exception (or maybe its null reference)  Because MSDN does say INSTANCE.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, no, it can't (ever return null) and won't.