# Adding an item to a dictionary results in a NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, asp.net, dictionary, nullreferenceexception

The following code has only thrown a NullReferenceException a handful of times over the last several months, but I'm not exactly sure why. The code isn't mine, but it looks pretty straight forward to me.

```
Type pageType = page.GetType();

if (_pages.TryGetValue(pageType, out value))
    return value;

// The following line throws the exception
return _pages[pageType] = new MyPage(_section.Pages[page]);
```

> [NullReferenceException: Object
>   reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.]
>   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey
>   key, TValue value, Boolean add) +210
>   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.set_Item(TKey
>   key, TValue value) +11

The only thing I can think of is that `pageType` is null when it's being used as a dictionary key, but apparently [that is not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201007/can-object-gettype-ever-return-null).

The code that calls it is simple:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);
    _mypage = GetPage();
}
```

I also thought that the error might be with the `_section.Pages`, but section is never null and never sets anything. If `.Pages[page]` returns null, the `MyPage` constructor simply returns. So what am I missing?

Comment: does your "MyPage" object overide  'GetHashCode' or 'Equals'?  Those are two possible calls that the Dictionary class would make on your objects.

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue and it turned out to be threading related.

By placing a sync lock around the line that inserts into the dictionary you can protect against the error:

This must be added as a class level definition:

```
private static object _sync = new object();
```

This is the insert statement surrounded by a sync lock:

```
lock (_sync)
{
    return _pages[pageType] = new MyPage(_section.Pages[page]);
}
```

This is the post that solved it for me: [Throw a NullReferenceException while calling the set_item method of a Dictionary object in a multi-threading scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1320621/throw-a-nullreferenceexception-while-calling-the-set-item-method-of-a-dictionary)

Answer (score 1):

I think it is throwing an exception because there is no element in the dictionary for the key **pageType**, and the accessor is returning null.

Try

```
MyPage newPage = new MyPage(_section.Pages[page]);
_pages.Add(pageType, newPage);
return newPage;
```

or if you are trying to reuse the entry if it exists:

```
MyPage newPage = new MyPage(_section.Pages[page]);
if (_pages.ContainsKey(pageType))
   _pages[pageType] = newPage;
else
   _pages.Add(pageType, newPage);
```

Comment: isn't accessing a dictionary by its indexer when it doesn't exist supposed to create the entry? http://en.csharp-online.net/BCL_Generics%E2%80%94Adding_and_Updating_Dictionary_Items

Comment: Dictionary indexer setter never throws exceptions when a new element is added. It could be thrown by getter, but in this case, it'd be the KeyNotFoundException, not the NullReferenceException.

Answer (score 1):

maybe the dictionary user defines somewhere else a custom ***IEqualityComparer*** that fails under some circumstances. Check where the code creates the dictionary to see if a custom comparer is passed. Maybe the comparer as well can be null, but this means this code never run...

Answer (score 0):

I would split them out for clarity, then see whats happening.

```
var section = _section.Pages[page];
var newPage = new MyPage(section);
_pages.Add(pageType,newPage);
return newPage;
```

Comment: I have now, but since this error happens very rarely, I have never been able to reproduce or debug it. It usually only shows up in a production environment.

Answer (score 0):

I think either _pages or pageType object is null. Another chance is _section object.

Comment: dev, _pages and _section aren't null. There are null checks I removed to keep the example brief. And pageType can't be null, because GetType will never return null.

Comment: If the exception is thrown by the provided code neither one of these could be null: _pages and pageType are used above the last line when TryGetValue is called, moreover if pageType would be null the ArgumentNullException would be thrown. The _section couldn't be null as well since we should not get into Dictionary.Insert method in this case.

Comment: @Brandon: actually GetType can return null, if we use proxy intercepting GetType calls, but it doesn't look to be your case indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Since TryGetValue didn't failed it looks to be caused by _section.Pages[page]. Since exception comes from Dictionary.Insert method, most probably, it's caused by equality/hash code implementation for the page. Are there custom implementations of IEqualityComparer or Equals/GetHashCode methods for page type? How these dictionaries are created?

Comment: the dictionaries are declared as private readonly at the class level. They do not override any of the methods.

Comment: @Brandon: how dictionaries are created (not declared)? Do you pass comparer to dictionary constructor? Are there Equals/GetHashCode overrides for page type? Surely, there are no overrides for dictionary, since it doesn't make sense.